# when app is not running and not in background how to call webservice

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried current location in terminate mode and suspended mode.currently i have fetch current location in background mode but not fetching in terminate mode.when user double click on home button and swipe the app in background how to fetch current location and call web service .

currently i have used below code .

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");

    self.shareModel = [LocationManager sharedManager];
    self.shareModel.afterResume = NO;

    [self.shareModel addApplicationStatusToPList:@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"];

     UIAlertView * alert;

    //We have to make sure that the Background App Refresh is enable for the Location updates to work in the background.
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusDenied) {

        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                          message:@"The app doesn't work without the Background App Refresh enabled. To turn it on, go to Settings > General > Background App Refresh"
                                         delegate:nil
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    } else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusRestricted) {

        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                          message:@"The functions of this app are limited because the Background App Refresh is disable."
                                         delegate:nil
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    } else {

        // When there is a significant changes of the location,
        // The key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey will be returned from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
        // When the app is receiving the key, it must reinitiate the locationManager and get
        // the latest location updates

        // This UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey key enables the location update even when
        // the app has been killed/terminated (Not in th background) by iOS or the user.

        NSLog(@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey : %@" , [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]);
        if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {

            // This "afterResume" flag is just to show that he receiving location updates
            // are actually from the key "UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey"
            self.shareModel.afterResume = YES;

            [self.shareModel startMonitoringLocation];
            [self.shareModel addResumeLocationToPList];
        }
    }


    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
    [self.shareModel restartMonitoringLocation];

    [self.shareModel addApplicationStatusToPList:@"applicationDidEnterBackground"];
}



- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");

    [self.shareModel addApplicationStatusToPList:@"applicationDidBecomeActive"];

    //Remove the "afterResume" Flag after the app is active again.
    self.shareModel.afterResume = NO;

    [self.shareModel startMonitoringLocation];
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"applicationWillTerminate");
    [self.shareModel addApplicationStatusToPList:@"applicationWillTerminate"];
}
```

Thanks
Yogesh Sharma

Comment: You can't run any process if your app is killed.

Comment: Delegate methods of location services are called even the app is not running. didUpdateLocations method called even the app is terminated. Search how to get user's location and in didUpdateLocations method you have to call a webservice. Its a headache kind of thing, you have to search a lot but it can be done for sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the user swipe the app in the background"? Regarding trying to use location to make your app run, startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges will only result in something when there has been a significant location change, duh, hence its name.

Comment: Thanks for reply .

Comment: i means that when user double click on home button and show the app in background and user killed the app than after how to fetch location and send the current lat long on web server.